# Run Spark streaming in virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, apache-spark, virtualization, spark-streaming

Is there any obvious performance degradation or drawback when deploy Spark streaming cluster in virtualized environment like Xen or KVM? What's the main reason?

Comment: Similar for any other virtualization... VM's are slower than Native machines. Hence anything running on VM will be slower than the same thing running on Native.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! But I want to know what's the features owned by Spark Streaming itself will aggravate this performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

The usual caveats about virtualization apply, but there is nothing specific to Spark or Spark Streaming.

I don't know of an article that would directly address this question. But the Spark petasort benchmark was run on EC2 and the article pays close attention to performance: https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html

Comment: Why do you think there would be any specific impact on Spark? Why did you ask this question?

Comment: Thank you for your attention! I'm sorry I didn't explain my question clearly enough. Actually, I know that cluster computing in virtualized environment will suffer a performance degradation because of some reasons such as resources competing by co-located VMs.The purpose I ask this question is that I want to know what's the internal cause of Spark Streaming itself will aggravate this, RDD partitioning, Task scheduling, or some other problem?

Comment: No, no such problems. We routinely run Spark applications inside Amazon EC2 VMs with good performance.

Comment: How about the heterogeneity of different hosts? In that case, computing capability of the nodes varies in the cloud which will lead to some problem like incorrect straggler judgement. It cannot be the same as the physical environment.

Comment: You're right. We run with speculative execution enabled (which I think is a good idea anyway). We are quite latency sensitive, as we use Spark to power an interactive UI. But we haven't seen any performance issues that we'd have identified as being caused by the virtualization. But this is just anecdotal evidence. If you are concerned, it's best if you test it yourself. And publish your results! I'd be very interested. I'll add one one relevant publication to the answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this work and I will publish my results in the future as soon as possible. Thank you for your reply and comments.